# Creating a class indexer operator[] allowing string parameter (string index)

Tags: c++, string, indexing, operator-overloading

I want to create a class in c++. This class must manage with a collection.
OK, no problem, I would like to use operator[] of course but, in this case, my wish is to index not by position, but by name ==> that means using a string indexer.

It seems that something of this kind is not so nice to my compiler:

```
// In hpp
class myclass {
   ...
   ...
   std::string operator[](const std::string& name);
}
// In cpp
std::string myclass::operator[](const std::string& name) {
   ...
}
// In main
myclass m;
std::string value = m["Name"];
```

Compiler tells me that he cannot solve this because operator[const char[5]] does not exists.
OK OK
I could figure this...
Compiler thinks that by calling m["Name"] I'm trying to call an operator admitting a char* and not a string... ok
Let's change the code with operator[] allowing a char* as parameter... nothing.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve such a result in c++ in a best practice way? I suppose that is a common problem to index by string and not by integer...
Thank you.

Comment: what happens when you try `std::string value = m[std::string("Name")];`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler is a *she*

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, std::string has a ctor that takes a char*, so that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine. See this example which compiles and works ok for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        std::string operator[] (const std::string& key) { std::cout << key << std::endl; return key; }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    std::string s = obj["50"];
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

And I see no reason it should not, since std::string has implicit constructor taking `const char*` so the conversion should be automatic.

Edit: From the comment it seems your problem was with your main beeing like this:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass obj();
    std::string s = obj["50"];
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

The reason:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.
>
> [ Note: since () is not permitted by the syntax for initializer,
>
> X a ();
>
> is not the declaration of an object of class X, but the declaration of a function taking no argument and returning an X.
>
> The form () is permitted in certain other initialization contexts (5.3.4, 5.2.3, 12.6.2). — end note ]

Comment: Well it's really strange... the error is this: "Invalid types mynamespace::myclass()[const char[5]] for array subscript"... my god what does it mean??? Even this sentence "myclass()[const char[5]]" is strange... is it referring to what? my one is a normal class having a public operator[] returning a std::string and taking a const std::string& as parameter... My compiler gives me an error when I use this operator at a line where I perform this operation: myclassinstance["value"]. If compile and comment that line, all class compiles...

Comment: Does your int main() contain something like this by any chance? MyClass obj(); That way you would get the "invalid types for array subscript" error you described.

Comment: I can't believe... not noticing something so simple.... well Plamik you area genius, how could you ever guess it??????? THANKS A LOT.... :)

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have provided should compile okay (providing the `operator` is `public` and you terminate your `class` declaration with a `;`). I suspect the compiler error is somewhere else.

Personally, I would use `std::map<std::string, std::string>` as the container class.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
    m["Foo"] = "Bar";
    m["Fez"] = "Baz";

    assert(m["Foo"] == "Bar");
    assert(m["Fez"] == "Baz");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... Well sure is a good idea using map... I'll think about it. :)

Comment: not a variant: the original question was about making custom container (such as AST node for example, as in my case)